# PHP -Session files being automatically recreated when removed

Tags: php, session, dokuwiki

I am doing some custom modifications to a dokuwiki site, but that may or may not have any bearing on the issue I am running into.

Here is the premise:  The dokuwiki site is using Oauth to log users in. They login on a Parent site and are redirected back to dokuwiki. There is a text file where is stores users that are logged in, as well as having normal session data stored. I have a requirement that when a users status changes on the Parent site, they will be logged out of the dokuwiki site and need to log in again in order to update their permission levels.

I have written a plugin/webhook that: when it receives the JSON file (which may have one or more accounts to process) from the Parent site, it loops through the session files, finds the ones that match the accounts that were sent, deletes those files

```
unlink($session_file);
```

,destroys the session for those specific session_ids,

```
session_id($session_id_to_destroy);
session_start();
session_destroy();
session_commit();
```

and removes the record from dokuwiki's text file.

All of that works great, except something keeps recreating the session files as soon as I remove them, and I cannot figure out what is doing it.

Does anyone know if there is some process built into Dokuwiki, or PHP, or Apache, that would cause this, or any ideas how to stop it?

Thanks in advance.

If it helps, the way I am testing is:

1. log the user in using OAuth
2. From a terminal, using CURL, send JSON
   data to webhook
3. I am var_dumping the list of files out in the session folder before it loops through
4. It does its thing and I can see that the file for the session id has been removed and the user has been removed from the text file
5. Look at the session folder again and see another file with a new session id has been created with the same users data in it that was just removed
6. Bang my head on my keyboard and cry

Comment: The next time a script calls `session_start()` the session file will be recreated.

Comment: Doing this will clear the session data, but a new empty session with the same ID will be created the next time a browser or client with that session ID in their cookie refreshes the page or visits again.

Comment: those are both good pieces of information, but then what is the solution?  It makes it sound like it is impossible to remove a session, which I am sure is not the case.

Comment: You can't remove the session, but all the session data is gone, so it's just like they started a new session. Why is it a problem if the new session ID is the same as the previous one?

Comment: @ErichMosier Your code starts a new (and importantly, **empty**) session for them. It just happens to be the same ID because of the cookie.

Comment: @Barmar The issue is that all the session data isn't gone.  It may get removed when the session file is deleted, but it is getting repopulated with the same data, albeit with a new session_id, when the session is recreated, so the user never gets logged out.

Comment: I see. The problem is that if a script is running in the session when you delete the file, it will save its session data when it exits, and that will recreate the file.

Comment: I just realized I may be confusing the session_id and the session file name.

Comment: @Barmar That's great to know.  I just don't understand how to not have that happen.

Comment: I'm also not sure why the webhook isn't waiting for the session lock, so it should remove the session after the other script finishes.